# How can I write text under the label of my Django model form?

Tags: python, html, django, django-forms, django-templates

I am working on a register form on Django. Under my TextFields label I want to write "For multiple purchased  units any of the item barcode works." Like below:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkrwI.png)

How can I add this to my form?

**forms.py**

```
class CustomerForm(forms.ModelForm):

    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       super(CustomerForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
       self.fields['orderorbarcode'].label = "Order ID or Item Barcode"
       



    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = (
        'orderorbarcode')
```

**models.py**

```
class Customer(models.Model):

    orderorbarcode = models.TextField(max_length=60,null=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.orderorbarcode
```

Comment: Have you tried the `help_text` property for the respective field?

Comment: No I am new at all the stuff. Can you show me how to do?

Comment: sure. please post your existing code for the model and form and I'd be happy to add to that.

Comment: ok. you can add `help_text` to the model field and it should be rendered. alternatively you can redefine the field in the form and add help_text there along with the label (instead of patching it in the init method).